# Allow Background activity

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am using broadcast receiver to listen for incoming calls in background service.

This feature working fine with all versions under android 10, but all versions above 10 can not listen in background until navigate to app info >> battery usage and activate this two configs
1- Allow Background activity
2- Allow Auto Launch

In this case the application working in background without any problems.

So, Is there any way to activate this two configs programmatically?
[Battery usage configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o46L.jpg)

Comment: The particular screen that you point to is unique to your device manufacturer. You will need to contact them to see what options there are, if any, for controlling those options programmatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.